# How to echo environment variable in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, github-actions

Goal is to print value of environment variable `GOPATH`

Below command in bash:

```
echo "$GOPATH"
```

gives output:

```
OPATH
```

---

GitHub runner runs this makefile target:

```
test:
    bash --version
    go env GOPATH
    export GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)
    echo "$GOPATH"
    go test -v -race -tags=unit -cover ./...
```

Below is the bash version used and pipeline output in GitHub runner(version: '2.286.1')

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ go env GOPATH
/home/vsts-agent/go
$ export GOPATH=
$ echo "OPATH"
OPATH
$ go test -v -race -tags=unit -cover ./...
go: downloading ...
```

Why `$G` is considered special token?

**Edit:**

Below changes:

```
test: env
    go env GOPATH
    export GOPATH=$$(go env GOPATH)
    echo "$$GOPATH"
    go test -v -race -tags=unit -cover ./...
```

give output:

```
$ go env GOPATH
/home/vsts-agent/go
$ export GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)
$ echo "$GOPATH"

$ go test -v -race -tags=unit -cover ./...
go: downloading ...
```

Comment: @StephenC Updated bash version in the query

Comment: Please show relevant parts of your actions yaml

Comment: @StephenC Updated query with more details on GitHub runner output

Comment: @overexchange Its a frequent issue with using Makefiles, the shell variables need to be accessed with a double `$$` inside it, so change it to `export GOPATH=$$(go env GOPATH)` and `echo "$$GOPATH"`

Comment: That's a makefile so you need to double the dollars: `$$GOPATH` and also `$$(go env GOPATH)` on the previous line.

Comment: @rici In makefile, do I need to say, `rm -rf $$GOPATH/pkg/mod/cache`

Comment: @StephenC, I See, that was misleading - removed my comment.

Comment: The reason you still see errors in your latest example is that every logical command line in a makefile recipe is invoked in a separate shell.  If you want to set shell variables on one line and have them still in effect on subsequent lines you have to put them into the same logical line, by adding semicolon / backslash to the end of the line to continue it to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

I understand now.

You are NOT in a bash shell here (as your question originally stated).

You are actually executing commands in a Makefile.  Make isn't running a shell and its handling of variables is different to a shell.

If you want to do a simple expansion of the variable `GOPATH` in a Makefile you write `$(GOPATH)`.  Your `$GOPATH` attempts to expand the (non-existent) variable `G`, not because `G` is special, but because that is how the Makefile syntax works.

Also, `export` means something different.  It is actually defining variables to be passed to a sub-make.  And you aren't using a sub-make here, as far as I can tell.

Makefiles are not shell scripts.  It looks like you have a lot of reading to do.

Reference:

- GNU Make manual - [6 How to use Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html)